# How to model muscle contraction force acting on two bones connected by joint in Unity/PhysX?

Tags: unity, physics

I'm trying to understand what is a correct way to model a muscle contraction in a physics engine like PhysX (Unity3D). Muscle that I'm modelling is connected to a bones in 2 points A and B.

Having a total force for the muscle `fTotal`, I'm trying to apply two forces in points A and B on corresponding bones, where magnitude of each force is a half of the total force. And of course force vectors are lying on the same AB line and pointing to the opposite directions towards the center of the muscle.

```
fTotal = ||fA|| + ||fB||
```

One thing that bothers me is a situation when one bone is fixed in space. Intuitively, all contraction force should be applied only to a single attachment point, however, my model will apply only 1/2 of a force. Can you suggest a better way to implement this?

Answer (score -2):

just saw your idea and it helped me on my project!
As for your problem: I think that the presence of a fixed object ("kinematic" I guess) is a problem specific enough to deserve a solution of it own. Just check if the other part is kinematic. If yes, then apply the full force on the movable part.

Comment: This is not really a useful insight to the person asking, maybe an example would be useful?